# Version control system for huge files?

Tags: version-control, large-files

I am looking for a quick but not-so-dirty way to do snapshots of a bunch of files totaling about 80 gigs. The issue here is that many of the files are around 1 GB large.

What is the best free version control system for this type of thing?

I know ZFS is an option, but I'd rather try something else first.

Comment: binary - although I don't know of any modern version control systems that have algorithms which distinguish between ascii and binary.

I'll try it out and post my results here.

Comment: The initial commit is busy, and using the file:// protocol, subversion is transferring an average of 1.5 MB per second. Pretty damn slow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Subversion will handle your > 1GB files with good natured aplomb for the most part but if there are many large changes expect the generation of diffs to take a while...

[*Subversion Best practices*](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/doc/user/svn-best-practices.html) has a section on large files:

> A nice feature of Subversion is that by design, there is no limit to
>   the size of files it can handle. Files are sent "streamily" in both
>   directions between Subversion client and server, using a small,
>   constant amount of memory on each side of the network.
>
> Of course, there are a number of practical issues to consider. While
>   there's no need to worry about files in the kilobyte-sized range (e.g.
>   typical source-code files), committing larger files can take a
>   tremendous amount of both time and space (e.g. files that are dozens
>   or hundreds of megabytes large.)
>
> To begin with, remember that your Subversion working copy stores
>   pristine copies of all version-controlled files in the .svn/text-base/
>   area. This means that your working copy takes up at least twice as
>   much disk space as the original dataset. Beyond that, the Subversion
>   client follows a (currently unadjustable) algorithm for committing
>   files:
>
> . Copies the file to .svn/tmp/ (can take a while, and temporarily uses
>   extra disk space))
>
> . Performs a binary diff between the tmpfile and the
>   pristine copy, or between the tmpfile and an empty-file if newly
>   added. (can take a very long time to compute, even though only a small
>   amount of data might ultimately be sent over the network)
>
> . Sends the
>   diff to the server, then moves the tmpfile into .svn/text-base/
>
> So
>   while there's no theoretical limit to the size of your files, you'll
>   need to be aware that very large files may require quite a bit of
>   patient waiting while your client chugs away. You can rest assured,
>   however, that unlike CVS, your large files won't incapacitate the
>   server or affect other users.

Comment: We've been using subversion now for this purpose for about two weeks, and it works just fine. Checkins on a data set of about 80 gigs spread across 130,000 files takes about 1 hour each night to check in. Daily deltas are 50 megs. Largest single file in the data set is 800 megs.

Comment: Great stuff, Ben.

Glad you found this useful.

Answer (score 3):

You might really want to try [Monotone](http://www.monotone.ca/) though, just check it out. You might find what you are looking for with it.

Comment: uring the monotone summit we exchanged some 2GB worth of photos using monotone itself, and it was quite fast.